# How would I fix this function?

Tags: python, function, optimization

Hey this is my first question so I hope I'm doing it right.

I'm trying to write a function that given a list of integers and N as the maximum occurrence, would then return a list with any integer above the maximum occurrence deleted. For example if I input:
`[20,37,20,21] #list of integers` and `1 #maximum occurrence`.
Then as output I would get:
`[20,37,21]` because the number 20 appears twice and the maximum occurrence is 1, so it is deleted from the list. Here's another example:
`Input: [1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2], 3`
`Output: [1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2]`

Here's what I wrote so far, how would I be able to optimize it? I keep on getting a timeout error. Thank you very much in advance.

```
def delete_nth(order,n):
    order = Counter(order)
    for i in order:
        if order[i] > n:
            while order[i] > n:
                order[i] - 1
    return order

print(delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1))
```

Comment: You don't "optimize" an infinite loop, you *fix* it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, didn't word it correctly, thanks for your comment tho! I'll fix that rn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove building the `Counter` at the beginning - and just have temporary dictionary as counter:

```
def delete_nth(order,n):
    out, counter = [], {}
    for v in order:
        counter.setdefault(v, 0)
        if counter[v] < n:
            out.append(v)
            counter[v] += 1
    return out

print(delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1))
```

Prints:

```
[20, 37, 21]
```

Comment: Note: You can combine two lines here and save a lookup: `if counter.setdefault(v, 0) < n:`. Or just make it a `collections.defaultdict(int)` so you can do `if counter[v] < n:` and it will auto-vivify on demand (`collections.Counter` would also work, but wouldn't be quite as efficient, since its `__missing__` is implemented in Python and doesn't actually create the key, so it would be invoked again when you did `counter[v] += 1`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I like the `if counter.setdefault(v, 0) < n:` approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
    while order[i] > n:
        order[i] - 1
```

That second line should presumably be `order[i] -= 1`, or any code that enters the loop will never leave it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a predicate with a default argument `collections.defaultdict` to retain state as your list of numbers is being filtered.

```
def delete_nth(numbers, n):
    from collections import defaultdict
    def predicate(number, seen=defaultdict(int)):
        seen[number] += 1
        return seen[number] <= n
    return list(filter(predicate, numbers))

print(delete_nth([1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2], 3))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: +1 for (perhaps overly) cute solution. I'd suggest moving the import out of the function just to avoid pointless per-call work, but otherwise, quite clever. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Right - if one really wanted to, one could eliminate the import altogether and use a regular dict. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I've renamed variables to something that had more meaning for me:

This version, though very short and fairly efficient, will output identical values adjacently:

```
from collections import Counter

def delete_nth(order, n):
    counters = Counter(order)
    output = []
    for value in counters:
        cnt = min(counters[value], n)
        output.extend([value] * cnt)
    return output

print(delete_nth([1,1,2,3,3,2,7,2,2,2,2], 3))
print(delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7]
[20, 37, 21]
```

This version will maintain original order, but run a bit more slowly:

```
from collections import Counter

def delete_nth(order, n):
    counters = Counter(order)
    for value in counters:
        counters[value] = min(counters[value], n)
    output = []
    for value in order:
        if counters[value]:
            output.append(value)
            counters[value] -= 1
    return output

print(delete_nth([1,1,2,3,3,2,7,2,2,2,2], 3))
print(delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 7, 2]
[20, 37, 21]
```